# Using one react state for multiple components

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple counter that I render an Items component that gets props and state as props. I want multiple renders of that same component to use just one counter state instead of counter1 counter2 etc...
Also I want to have just increase and decrease function instead of multiple. Hope the code explains what im trying to say. Is there anyway to do this?

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./NavBar";
import Items from "./Items";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super();
this.state = {
  counter1: 0,
  counter2: 0,
  counter3: 0,
};
}
render() {
//Counter 1
const Increase1 = () => {
  this.setState({ counter1: this.state.counter1 + 1 });
};

const Decrease1 = () => {
  if (this.state.counter > 0) {
    this.setState({ counter1: this.state.counter1 - 1 });
  }
};

//Counter 2
const Increase2 = () => {
  this.setState({ counter2: this.state.counter2 + 1 });
};

const Decrease2 = () => {
  if (this.state.counter > 0) {
    this.setState({ counter2: this.state.counter2 - 1 });
  }
};

//Counter 3
const Increase3 = () => {
  this.setState({ counter3: this.state.counter3 + 1 });
};

const Decrease3 = () => {
  if (this.state.counter > 0) {
    this.setState({ counter3: this.state.counter3 - 1 });
  }
};
return (
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <div className="container mt-4">
      <button className="btn btn-primary mr-4">Redo</button>
      <button
        className="btn btn-secondary"
        onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
      >
        Reload
      </button>
      <Items
        amount={this.state.counter1}
        increase={Increase1}
        decrease={Decrease1}
      />
      <Items
        amount={this.state.counter2}
        increase={Increase2}
        decrease={Decrease2}
      />
      <Items
        amount={this.state.counter3}
        increase={Increase3}
        decrease={Decrease3}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

And here is the Items Component

```
import React from "react";

 function Items(props) {
 console.log(props);
 return (
<div>
  <h6 className="mt-3">{props.amount}</h6>
  <button className="btn btn-success mr-3" onClick={props.increase}>
    +
  </button>
  <button className="btn btn-info mr-3" onClick={props.decrease}>
    -
  </button>
  <button className="btn btn-danger mr-3">Delete</button>
</div>
);
}

export default Items;
```

Sorry for the confusing code it was weird to get into a code block

Answer (score 1):

About the idea you can use only one `increase` and `decrease` function for multiple `Items` by specific a `key` for each `Item`

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './NavBar';
import Items from './Items';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      counter1: 0,
      counter2: 0,
      counter3: 0,
    };
  }

  increase = (key) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [key]: prevState[key] + 1 }));
  };

  decrease = (key) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [key]: prevState[key] - 1 || 0}));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container mt-4">
          <button className="btn btn-primary mr-4">Redo</button>
          <button
            className="btn btn-secondary"
            onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
          >
            Reload
          </button>
          <Items
            amount={this.state.counter1}
            increase={() => this.increase('counter1')}
            decrease={() => this.decrease('counter1')}
          />
          <Items
            amount={this.state.counter2}
            increase={() => this.increase('counter2')}
            decrease={() => this.decrease('counter2')}
          />
          <Items
            amount={this.state.counter3}
            increase={() => this.increase('counter3')}
            decrease={() => this.decrease('counter3')}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks that helped clean up my code alot. Im still a beginner if its no trouble could you explain the code a bit more? But also fine if not thanks for answering